# Embed a Collection of forms

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity **Game** and an entity **Player** , and each game has 3 players

I'd like to know how to embed **PlayerType** in **GameTpe** for 3 times and then display them in form.twig without using javascript

**GameType**

```
class GameType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
  $builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))
    ->add('description', 'text',  array('required' => true))
    ->add('date', 'date', array('required' => true)) 

    ->add('players',  new PlayerType()); //how to embed playerType 3 times
  }
```

**PlayerType**

```
class PlayerType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder
    ->add('name', 'texet', array('required' => true))
    ->add('age', 'integer',  array('required' => true));
    //............

}
```

**form.twig**

```
<form method="post" action="" >

        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.description) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.date) }}

    // how to display this form 3 times

        {{ form_widget(form.players) }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: You want to use a form collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and then simply add three player entities to your game entity.

Answer (score 0):

If your game always have three players why don't you add three fields to **Game** entity?

Then for example use getter to collect them all.

Comment: Do you think this is the best solution ?

Comment: No, but you said you don't want to use JS ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. That solution wouldn't work. You can try this instead.